# PrimeFaces splitbutton removal

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My splitButton should not have any text on the button but I have menu items. I have to remove the button instead leaving blank except menu option.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Menu Button](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menubutton.jsf).If you dont have any text on the menu button, Its shows only down arrow icon for menu options.

Comment: . yeah i have used that. the thing is those widget i am using in datatable. if i click the menu of split button , row  will be selected but if click the button , row ill not be select. so i am asking you remove only button except those menu in splitbutton